# How does the following equation get the new Un results after they let Un= Tn +1. Can’t understand the intermediate steps!

Tags: sequences-and-series

$T_0+1=1; T_n +1= 2T_{n-1} + 2$, for $n>0$

Let $U_n= T_n + 1$. Then,

$U_0 = 1; U_n= 2U_{n-1}$, for $n>0$

How does the above equation get the new $U_n$ results of $U_0=1$ and $U_n=2U_{n-1}$ after they let $U_n= T_n +1$? I can’t understand the intermediate steps!

Comment: Two things are confusing: 1: $T_0 + 1 = 1$. Why is this not written as $T_0 = 0$? 2. $U_n = 2 U_n - 1$. This would imply that $-U_n = -1 \implies U_n = 1$, which is also confusing :(

Comment: Well, @SiddharthBhat , I think he wants to change the sequence in a new form ($U_n$), so he writes in $T_0+1$ like that. The second question is actually some typo. You can see the new edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $U_{n-1}=T_{n-1}+1$. Then,
$$T_n+1=2T_{n-1}+2\\T_n+1=2(T_{n-1}+1) \\ U_n=2U_{n-1}$$

Comment: Issac, in ur second step is there a typo ? Isn’t it 2Tn-1 + 2??

Comment: oh ya thanks for reminding

Comment: Now, it makes sense. Thanks!